# itextsharp Maintain zoom level to inherit zoom even if link is clicked on the PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I'm using itextsharp for converting the existing PDF to converted PDF for the below functions:

- Changing the zoom level to "Inherit zoom" for all the pages
- Removing the URL links from PDF(mostly http://)

There are few action links still available in converted PDF for going across the pages in the same PDF viz., from page 3 to page 1, when user does this action the converted PDF lose the zoom level from "Inherit zoom".

Please can anyone help me to guide on this issue.

Thanks

Regards,
JD

Comment: Sharing your code might help.

Comment: ok i will soon share the code for removing the links and setting the zoom level

Comment: possible duplicate of [All links of existing pdf change the action property to inherit zoom - iText library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828782/all-links-of-existing-pdf-change-the-action-property-to-inherit-zoom-itext-lib)

Comment: I will try to implement and let you know my update. Thanks Bruno for sharing this.